# Can't launch Gears of War 3 in offline mode on 360?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, gears-of-war-3

I just downloaded Gears of War 3 after a long while to my Xbox Hard Drive, and decided to play launch the game from there. When I went to launch the game from the drive, the Xbox displays an error message simply stating that I can't launch Gears of War 3.

So when I go online to Xbox Live, and the game launch just fine. But when I go offline to play locally, the game refuses to launch at all. Is there anything I can do to remedy this? I don't want to stay online all the time.

I have other games installed to my Hard Drive, such as Forza Horizon 2 and Gears of War 1, and those work just fine offline, but Gears of War 3 is the issue here.

Comment: So if you start the game signed into live it works, but if you arent signed into live, it wont start? What would happen if you started it in live, and once the game was loaded disabled live?

Comment: Tried that. It says that I have 10 minutes to play before I will be forcefully kicked out.

Comment: Well then... I dont remember NEEDING an internet connection to just play like campaign or anything. But I havent played that game in like 6 years. Sorry I cant be more help :/

Comment: No worries. I have the disc version of the game, but my brother and I like to play over system link, so I bought this digital code from a vendor locally. Go figure, might as well just get the disc :p As for the no internet connection bit, I think that is because you were playing on a disc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the solution is simply sign into Xbox Live using my Xbox Account, and continue with normal game operations from that point onward.

For some reason, Xbox Live also affects System Linking. Go figure...